# How to not crash if a foreign key refers to a null row while the key is not nullable?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have this table "regions":

### id | name | parent_id

1  | whatever | 100000

where the parent_id should be self referencing to the id, meaning this row geographically belongs to 100000.

However due to the data being imported at the beginning is dirty, the row with id 100000 doesn't exist.

Therefore in the given Entity:

```
@Entity("regions")
public class Region {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Region parent;

    ...

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    public Region getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Region parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

When I do a list with hibernate:

```
    Session session = sessionHandler.getSession(); //gets current session
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        return (List<T>)session.createQuery("FROM regions").list();
    }
    catch(HibernateException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        throw ex;
    }finally {
        sessionHandler.close(); 
    }
```

It will throw exception:

```
org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [whatever.entities.Region#6046193]
```

Which indicates region of id 6046193 doesn't exist. As explained before, I expect something like this would happen.

My questions, given I can't edit the parent_id column to nullable, is it a way to handle this exception so that the system ignores the exception and keeps the program going?

Comment: I think the root cause of the problem is the "dirty" data, and not Hibernate.  You should maintain the integrity of your data within MySQL.  If the `parent_id` column must always refer to an existing record, then add a constraint to this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the fetch type of the many to one relationship to lazy.

```
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
public Region getParent() {
    return parent;
}
...
```

I guess then hibernate would not throw an error during the "select all", and you can handle the error when you first call the getter, if you do it like that.

But I am not 100% sure if this works, and **I don't think it is a really good solution**. I really think you should sanitize your data during/after the import.

If you do not sanitize your data, you'll have to keep workarounds for the problems in the code **forever**. What if, in the future, someone removes the `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, because they think it would lead to better performance? Your application will break in an unexpected way, just because your entities do not reflect correctly what is in your database.

You said you cannot set the `parent_id` to null since the column is not nullable. But what about creating dummy entries for the missing IDs? You could do that right after importing your dirty data, before you start up your application for the first time.

Also, just changing the column to nullable (assuming that you can do that, for a moment) won't work anyway. You would still have to sanitize the data - in that case, you would have to set all the `parent_id`s to null when the row with the referenced id does not exist.

Comment: The problem is that your domain model classes don't accurately represent your relationships.  The above domain model dictates a valid FK constraint exists between `parent_id` and `id` of the same table, of which all legacy rows invalidate.

Comment: @Naros yes, that's why I wrote that the better solution is to sanitize the data... Also, as far as I understood, only some "legacy" rows violate that assumption.

Comment: @DavidTanzer the data is from 3rd party, which breaks our major assumption. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

I would say your data model design is flawed.

From a relational perspective, you're using `parent_id` to represent a not nullable self referencing foreign key to `id`.  This means that whatever value you place inside `parent_id` should have a matching row with the same `id` value.  This should automatically create a foreign key constraint violation by inserting the invalid rows you cite in your post.

If the field must remain `nullable=false`, you could create a sentinel row and any legacy data you load with invalid `parent_id` references, could be changed to use the sentinel row's `id` just so the data model is valid.  If the data model can be altered slightly, a `legacy_parent_id` could hold the legacy reference and your code could have differing logic paths based on the sentinel row.

The only other idea I have assuming you can modify the data model slightly, would be to consider using a discriminator that separates the legacy rows from the non-legacy rows.

In the legacy model, you'd have a `legacy_parent_id` you populate that is simply an integer.  In the non-legacy model, you could have the `parent_id` foreign key validated relationship that is not nullable.